# Row being added to MySQL database but no other data from the html form using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The data from the form is not getting saved into the database but a row is being added, I am hosting with Go Daddy. It worked perfectly on my local  but now live seems to be not working. Please find below the code I am using:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{

    $fName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fName']);
    $surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
    $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
    $tel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tel']);
    $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $bool = true;
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

    if (!$con)  
    {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }   

    mysql_select_db("db name", $con);      

    $sql="INSERT INTO customer (custNo, fName, surname, postcode, tel, mobile, email, timestamp)
    VALUES (NULL, '$fName','$surname','$postcode', '$tel', '$mobile',  '$email', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else{
        echo "Successfully Registered ";
    }
}
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

and here is the html form

```
<form action="insert.php" method = "post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for='fName'>Enter name:</label>
            <input type= "text" name = "fName" required="required" maxlength="50"/>   <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for='surname'>Enter surname:</label>
            <input type= "text" name="surname" maxlength="50" required="required"/> <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for='postcode'>Enter postcode:</label>
            <input type= "text" name="postcode" maxlength="7"/> <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for='tel'>Enter home no:</label>
            <input type= "text" name="tel" maxlength="50" />  <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for='mobile'>Enter mobile no:</label>
            <input type= "text" name="mobile" maxlength="50"/> <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for='email'>Enter email * </label>
            <input type= "text" name="email" required="required"/> <br/></br>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your variables aren't empty after running your `mysql_real_escape_string()` methods?

Comment: debug each variable. echo the $sql, then copy and paste manually into godaddy and see if any error comes up

Comment: so if i  do not check if my variables are empty and they are not empty is that why no data is showing in the database?  i am going to add code to check now thank you

Comment: i added this code just below the mysql_real_escape_strings()

Comment: if(empty($fName) || empty($surname) || empty($postcode) || empty($tel) ||
    empty($mobile) || empty($email))

Comment: it still only showing the timestamp on the new row added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First :**

---

Warning

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

If you didn't check $_POST['password'], it could be anything the user wanted! For example:

```
$_POST['username'] = 'aidan';
$_POST['password'] = "' OR ''='";

// Query database to check if there are any matching users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND password='{$_POST['password']}'";
mysql_query($query);
```

This means the query sent to MySQL would be:

> SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='aidan' AND password='' OR ''=''

This would allow anyone to log in without a valid password.

---

### To your problem !

**All your variables are empty due to this fact ...**

> A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string()
>   otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is
>   returned.

put your **mysql_real_escape_string()** after connect.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con) { ...}

mysql_select_db("db name", $con);
//-------------- next after connect not before !!! --------
$fName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fName']);
[...]
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$bool = true;

$sql="INSERT INTO customer (...) VALUES (...)";
```

Comment: Thank you very much moskito-x and every one , it worked by placing the mysql-real_escxape_string() after the connect

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the varibales.

try changing the $sql line to this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customer (custNo, fName, surname, postcode, tel, mobile, email, timestamp)  VALUES (NULL, '" . $fName . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $postcode . "', '" . $tel . "', '". $mobile . "', '" . $email . "', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')";
```

Comment: hi i changed the insert statement but again a row was added but no other data showed up except the timestamp

Comment: Can you show the  $sql statement generated (`echo $sql`). There may be some error with the sql

Comment: after the registration the sql message says : Successfully Registered and when i check database a new row is added but the data is empty for the other columns except timestamp

Comment: There is some problem with your generated sql statement. Please debug that. Or post the sql statement generated.

Comment: since i added the code to check if variables are not empty here is the sql statement generated: You did not fill out the required fields.Successfully Registered. A new row is still being added with no data

Comment: if(empty($fName) || empty($surname) ||  empty($email))
{
    // error message.";
}
   
 $bool = true;
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con) 
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
 mysql_select_db("db name", $con); 
 
 $sql="INSERT INTO customer ("table names")  VALUES (NULL, '" . $fName . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $postcode . "', '" . $tel . "', '". $mobile . "', '" . $email . "', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')";
 
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  } else{
 //"message"
  }

Comment: You are telling us the script return message, we want to see the raw SQL before executing, echo/dump the SQL variable and paste it on SO.